# Object.create() functioning

Tags: javascript

```
var task = {};

task.prop1 = "prop1 value";
task.prop2 = "prop2 value";

console.log(task);

var newTask = Object.create(task);

console.log(newTask);
```

In this case, why is `newTask` printing empty? As I understand it, shouldn't it print the properties of `task`?

Edit: I found out that when we create the object through Object.create(task), we are assigning newTask's prototype as task, hence new task does not have the native task object's proprties which can be verified via getOwnProperty() on the newTaskObject. But when we carefully examine, when we try to access the properties of task object through newTask, the prototype chain is rolled up and we dont get undefined. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `console.log` for both values print the same object. `newTask` is not empty if you check correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the properties of `task` through it – try `console.log(newTask.prop1)` – but your browser’s console only lists [own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain) when summarizing objects.

Expand it to see the prototype:

[image: Screenshot of expanded object in Firefox console]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
var task = function() {
  this.prop1 = "prop1 value";
  this.prop2 = "prop2 value";
}

var newTask = new task();

console.log(newTask);
```

Javascript can create an instance of a function which is treated as a class.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create()` method creates a new object, using an existing object to provide the newly created object's `__proto__`. You can refer to either `newTask.prop1` or `newTask.__proto__.prop1`